# Merge condition SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on someone's code and trying to figure out what below syntax is doing. I have written several merge statement but never used this kind of on clause. Can any one please help me in understanding if there is any specific scenarios where we use these kind of clauses (1=1)?

```
MERGE T
USING S on 1=1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
Insert (col1,col2)
Values(col1,col2)
```

Comment: This alone doesn't work i am sure u should also have when matched Update statement. It is not a good example of joining source and target without defining columns

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: it did work without update. What i can think of is whoever has written this trying to insert record from S in table T only if its empty. I tested with this "Declare  @a  table (id int,value int)
--insert into @a values (5,12)
Declare  @b  table (id int,value int)
insert into @b values (1,13)
insert into @b values (2,13)


Merge @a a using @b b on 1=1
when not matched then 
insert  values(id,value);


select * from @a"

Answer (score 1):

It is clear by the query that has not to update any data only insertion for all data as 1=1 means always true for all;

Comment: Always true case will move code execution to "When Matched". When not matched will never be executed. What i understood so far is this clause only will be executed if Table "T" is empty else do nothing.

Comment: 1=1 will match all columns if matched then it will not insert data and when not matched then it will insert data.